# How JavaScript DOM events are continuously handled even if they are inside a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

lets imagine a scenario

```
function clickEventCheck() {

    document.querySelector('#some-id').addEventListener('click', () => {

             console.log("The button is clicked");
      });
}

clickEventCheck();
```

Now I get that for the first time the 'clickEventCheck' function is getting called and we can handle the click event.
But now the execution stack is empty so how the event handler line of code which is inside our function(which has returned) still gets executed every time we click the button?

Comment: Because when the function is called, the `click` listener is attached to the element.

Comment: By using an event handler you attach it to the corresponding object. Each time the event is fired (example onclick) the defined function is called. This has nothing to do with the execution stack

Comment: `addEventListener` adds a handler to be called later. It does not wait for the event.

Comment: so the DOM element gets a new property as an event listener and the event is handled by the obj itself not by function that we called. is my understanding right> @Aaron

Comment: You can inspect the handlers of an element by inspecting it on the browser. You see all handlers attached to the element

Answer (score 0):

When the function is called `click` listener is added to the element with id `some-id`. So, whenever you click the element, the code inside the `callback` function gets executed.

Until and unless the `click` listener is not explicitly removed from the element i:e element with id `some-id`, it will listen to `click` events.

```js
function clickHandler() {
  console.log('The button is clicked');
}

function clickEventCheck() {
  document.querySelector('#some-id').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}

clickEventCheck();

document.querySelector('.remove').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#some-id').removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

```html
<button id="some-id">Click Me</button>

<button class="remove">Remove Click Listener</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot,  totally understood your explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is doing more than just executing your code sequentially, line by line. In the background there is also something running called the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). This frequently checks another stack to see if any other instructions are there and if so runs those, starting additional chains of execution called frames.

Two nice properties of those frames is that they will keep running as long as they can so you don't have to reason about random switching between them, and they don't block, so once a frame can't execute any further, the engine will look for another frame to execute from the stack. This also leads to smooth switching between frames provided you are not doing CPU-heavy execution (which isn't normally what JavaScript's used for).

Practically what might happen is one frame (frame A) makes an I/O request, and provides a callback function when it does so. Frame A then runs out of code to execute and the event loop picks the next frame (frame B) to run. In the background, when the I/O request completes the callback function will be added to the stack—and then when frame B runs out of code, the event loop can pick up that callback and execute it in yet another frame. The same process could apply for a button click, a mouse move, or any asynchronous process you can get the computer to do.

In this way a large number of I/O connections can be smoothly handled simultaneously and this is a big selling point of NodeJs.

A lot of callbacks can get messy quickly and that's why there also exists concepts like Promises and async functions, which are topics for another day.